# How to filter a dropdown list based on a already pre selected list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, filter

I am trying to filter the dropdown list based on the first pre-selected list. The first list is contains 'United States' as pre selection and the list to be filtered is the second drop down menu. I would appreciate inputs on how to solve this.

```
<ul>
    <li class="">Argentina</li>
    <li class="selected">United States</li>
    <li class="">Australia</li>
</ul>
<select data-val="false" data-val-length="Only 64 characters allowed." data-val-length-max="64" data-val-required="Country code can't be empty" id="CountryCode" name="CountryCode" class="valid">
    <option value="ARG">Argentina</option>
    <option value="USA">United States</option>
    <option value="AUS">Australia</option>
</select>
```

Regards,

Adit

Comment: Please refresh your question, just title would be difficult us to understand, and what the jQuery that you've tried....

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/H6bw5/1/ or do you want to change the select value depending on what <li> element you click?

Comment: @user3632027 Hi :) `lkndkfnvlk`?

Comment: Hi Anton..sorry about that. Typo.

Comment: Thanks Anton,for the quick reply.

Comment: The thing is that the user input is not required,as the list is pre-selected, in this case 'us'. The output in the dropdown should have only contain 'United States' with the other countries hidden.

Comment: @user3632027 I've added an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**jQuery**

Get the selected country and then find the `<option>` using attribute-equals-selector and hide the siblings

```
$(function () {
    var country = $('.selected').data('country');
    $('#CountryCode').find('[value="' + country + '"]').siblings().hide();
    $('#CountryCode').val(country);
});
```

**HTML**

Add `data-*` attribute to the html elements

```
<ul>
    <li data-country="ARG">Argentina</li>
    <li data-country="USA" class="selected">United States</li>
    <li data-country="AUS">Australia</li>
</ul>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/H6bw5/3/)

Comment: Hi Anton,Thanks for your answer. Would it be possible to do this without the data attribute.? That is just by comparing the text from the list menu to the dropdown menu items.